# Android IllegalArgumentException lockCanvas()

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-canvas, surfaceview

I've been struggling with this exception and I've looked around but there's nothing to help me.

Here's the code

```
package com.example.surfacetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.Surface.OutOfResourcesException;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class BoardSurfaceActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private static final String TAG = BoardSurfaceActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private BoardSurface bS;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        bS = new BoardSurface(this);
        setContentView(bS);
        Log.d(TAG, "View added");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Destroying...");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping...");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Pausing...");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Resuming...");
        super.onResume();

    }

    public class BoardSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Runnable {
        final String TAG = BoardSurface.class.getSimpleName();
        private Stuff stuff;
        Thread t = null;
        SurfaceHolder holder;
        boolean isItOk = false;

        public BoardSurface(Context context) {
            super(context);
            holder = getHolder();
            getHolder().addCallback(this);
            stuff = new Stuff(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher), 50, 50);
            t = new Thread(this);
            setFocusable(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Surface created");
            resume();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Surface Destroyed");
            pause();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // delegating event handling to the droid
                stuff.handleActionDown((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

                // check if in the lower part of the screen we exit
                if (event.getY() > getHeight() - 50) {
                    ((Activity) getContext()).finish();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Coords: x=" + event.getX() + ",y=" + event.getY());
                }
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                // the gestures
                if (stuff.isTouched()) {
                    // the droid was picked up and is being dragged
                    stuff.setX((int) event.getX());
                    stuff.setY((int) event.getY());
                }
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // touch was released
                if (stuff.isTouched()) {
                    stuff.setTouched(false);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
            stuff.draw(canvas);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (isItOk) {
                holder = getHolder();
                if (holder.getSurface().isValid()) {

                    Canvas c = null;
                    try {
                        // make sure holder is updated
                        c = holder.lockCanvas(null);
                        if (c != null) {
                            synchronized (holder) {
                                draw(c);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (c != null) {
                            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void pause() {
            isItOk = false;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    t.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
            t = null;
        }

        public void resume() {
            if (t.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
                t = new Thread(this);
                isItOk = true;
                t.start();
            } else {
                isItOk = true;
                t.start();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

What is super strange is that I have this trace :

```
10-22 08:54:41.153: D/BoardSurface(17298): Surface created
10-22 08:54:41.394: E/memalloc(17298): /dev/pmem: Failed to map buffer size:24641536 offset:23699456 fd:56 Error: Invalid argument
10-22 08:54:41.394: E/gralloc(17298): Could not mmap handle 0x89e2b8, fd=56 (Invalid argument)
10-22 08:54:41.394: E/gralloc(17298): gralloc_register_buffer: gralloc_map failed
10-22 08:54:41.394: W/GraphicBufferMapper(17298): registerBuffer(0x89e2b8) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
10-22 08:54:41.394: E/GraphicBuffer(17298): unflatten: registerBuffer failed: Invalid argument (-22)
10-22 08:54:41.394: E/memalloc(17298): /dev/pmem: Failed to map buffer size:24641536 offset:23699456 fd:56 Error: Invalid argument
10-22 08:54:41.394: E/gralloc(17298): Could not mmap handle 0x89e2b8, fd=56 (Invalid argument)
10-22 08:54:41.394: E/libgenlock(17298): perform_lock_unlock_operation: GENLOCK_IOC_DREADLOCK failed (lockType0x1,err=Bad file number fd=56)
10-22 08:54:41.394: E/gralloc(17298): gralloc_lock: genlock_lock_buffer (lockType=0x2) failed
10-22 08:54:41.394: W/GraphicBufferMapper(17298): lock(...) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
10-22 08:54:41.394: W/Surface(17298): failed locking buffer (handle = 0x89e2b8)
10-22 08:54:41.424: E/SurfaceHolder(17298): Exception locking surface
10-22 08:54:41.424: E/SurfaceHolder(17298): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
10-22 08:54:41.424: E/SurfaceHolder(17298):     at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
10-22 08:54:41.424: E/SurfaceHolder(17298):     at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:236)
10-22 08:54:41.424: E/SurfaceHolder(17298):     at android.view.SurfaceView$4.internalLockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:807)
10-22 08:54:41.424: E/SurfaceHolder(17298):     at android.view.SurfaceView$4.lockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:787)
10-22 08:54:41.424: E/SurfaceHolder(17298):     at com.example.surfacetest.BoardSurfaceActivity$BoardSurface.run(BoardSurfaceActivity.java:137)
10-22 08:54:41.424: E/SurfaceHolder(17298):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

in my running loop.

But here's the tricky part ! When I press back (not HOME) then start the app from the menu again. It just simply works.

So I really don't know what I'm missing.

Additional info : I'm running on a HTC Sensation XE, CM 10.2 (Android 4.3.1)

EDIT:

The device is not the issue here. Tried with another HTC on stock ROM.

EDIT 2 :

Even though I check :

```
if (holder.getSurface().isValid())
```

Which is specifically saying that lockcanvas() will succeed if it is true, I get this exception

```
10-22 10:11:27.688: E/SurfaceHolder(22195): Exception locking surface
10-22 10:11:27.688: E/SurfaceHolder(22195): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
10-22 10:11:27.688: E/SurfaceHolder(22195):     at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
10-22 10:11:27.688: E/SurfaceHolder(22195):     at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:236)
10-22 10:11:27.688: E/SurfaceHolder(22195):     at android.view.SurfaceView$4.internalLockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:807)
10-22 10:11:27.688: E/SurfaceHolder(22195):     at android.view.SurfaceView$4.lockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:787)
10-22 10:11:27.688: E/SurfaceHolder(22195):     at com.example.surfacetest.BoardSurfaceActivity$BoardSurface.run(BoardSurfaceActivity.java:144)
10-22 10:11:27.688: E/SurfaceHolder(22195):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

EDIT 3 :

Works on Galaxy S4 Stock ROM and Emulator Intelx86 4.2.2

Answer (score 1):

@CinetiK: Post the rest of your stacktrace.

HTC devices are notorious when it comes to rotation and surface tests. Have you tried this:

1. Restart your phone.
2. Go to Safe mode (i.e. restart the phone and when you see the HTC logo, long press Volume down button). The phone will restart again and go into Safe mode.
3. Once phone is in Safe mode, go to Settings | Display & Gestures | G-Sensor Calibration. Then, calibrate your phone while ensuring your phone rests on a flat surface. Once calibration is successfully completed, restart the phone in normal mode.

If the above steps still do not fix the error, and since you're using **CM 10.2**, I would recommend testing your Android app on stock ROMs first. While I have nothing against custom Android ROMs (I used them myself), from experience I have had more unexplained errors on custom ROMs than stock ROMs. Try a stock ROM first and see if you still get the same error.

Comment: Didn't help, tried with the stock HTC ROM on ICS and didn't work.

Comment: The `IllegalArgumentException` often mean a method failed because a parameter, context, or a referenced field is null. Before you do this `if (holder.getSurface().isValid())` can you do this first `if (holder != null)` then do your other codes after this check.

Comment: Kinda makes no sense because I couldn't get anything with getSurface() if holder was null so... I'll try but I'm pretty sure it will just pass.